# character missing when reading from file in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

in shell script I'm trying to read a file line by line using while loop but character 'n' is replaced with blank space in all lines.

here is the output of cat namespaces.tx

```
     cat namespaces.txt
default
kube-node-lease
kube-public
kube-system
name
mane
mann
```

here is the output it is printing when reading from while loop

```
while IFS=$'\n' read -r line; do echo $line; done < namespaces.txt
default
kube- ode-lease
kube-public
kube-system
ame
ma e
ma
```

Comment: Please add output of `echo "$SHELL"` and `file namespaces.txt` to your question (no comment).

Comment: You can use hexdump(1) or an hex editor to look what the original file really contains. It looks suspicious...

Comment: My guess is that the script is running under a shell other than bash, and that `IFS` is also being set to `$'\n'` somewhere else in the script. Does the script have a shebang, and how are you running it? Is there anything else in the script involving `IFS`? Also, at least for the purposes of `read`, setting `IFS` to newline doesn't make much sense, since `read` treats newline as a line terminator and therefore it'll never occur within a line.

Comment: Saw that just now: that `IFS=$...` is quite strange (and probably wrong)!

Comment: @Cyrus here is the out of echo "$SHELL"                                                                 
 echo "$SHELL"
/bin/bash                                                                                                                      file namespaces.txt
namespaces.txt: ASCII text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
done < namespaces.txt
```

This is the correct way to read and print a line at a time. `"$line"` is quoted, and `IFS` can be set to empty.

Check for `IFS=\n`, or similar, in your script. Somewhere, you have set `IFS` to contain `n`.  Then when you print `$line` with no quotes, it gets split in to multiple words by `IFS` (`n`), and echo prints each word given to it, with a space in between.

Comment: Thank @Dan this worked. I thought about it but i was thinking it will split it into a new array element at character 'n'. I don't have much understanding of IFS, might messed up somewhere.  thank you so much again